# How to import private Slack channels to Mattermost

Tags: import, slack, mattermost

How to import private channel from Slack (with history) into Mattermost? Do you know a Slack plugin that does a good export that Mattermost can import? I have found a Slack plugin from export.fountstudio.com which though, can't be imported well, most of the time it fails.

I was looking for a valid format of Mattermost message import but I can't find that either, and also I can't find any Mattermost export plugin to see correct format...

Any advices please?

Comment: You should be able to find message formats from their plugin reference - https://developers.mattermost.com/extend/plugins/server/reference/

Comment: Did not find any good way. Mattermost import/export documentation and support is bad, stopping the process.

Answer (score 1):

From the Mattermost documentation:

Direct Messages and Private Channels cannot be imported. Slack does not include these messages when generating the export archive.

https://docs.mattermost.com/administration/migrating.html?highlight=slack#limitations

Comment: Well, I have a way how to export Slack private channels, so my problem is now at side of Mattermost, which can't describe what it can import or what are precisely the errors on import.